# Hibernate Criteria order by term length

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria

I want to order my terms by lenght,which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT term FROM <table_name> where term  like '%now%' order by length(term ) asc;
```

in hibernate.

For the moment this is my criteria code:

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(myClass.class);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("term")));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("term", "%xyz%"));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("term"));
    criteria.setMaxResults(10);
    List<String> list = criteria.list();
```

Cheers

Comment: you need to add `criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("term"));`

Comment: I already tried this and it did not order by the number of characters.
Thank you for your reply Eugen

Answer (score 1):

According to this JPAQL has a length function.

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string

and 10.2.5.16

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28613_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html

There's some comment in 8.1.6 here about the equivalent Criteria:

http://webdev.apl.jhu.edu/~jcs/ejava-javaee/coursedocs/605-784-site/docs/content/html/jpa-query-criteria-function.html

None of the covers applying it to order by clause rather than where clause but hopefully of use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can order in Criteria something like that, you need to use JPQL for that kind of order.

JPQL Order Documentation: [Documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_query.html)